# Extend every single string in a list with punctuation

Tags: python-2.7

I have a long list like:

```
['This', 'Hello', 'Good', ...]
```

Now i want a new list that looks like:

```
['This', 'This.','This,','This?','This!','This:','Hello','Hello.','Hello,','Hello?','Hello!','Hello:', 'Good', 'Good.', ...]
```

So i want to add punctuation to every word. Is this even possible?

Comment: Yes ofcourse it is. What did you trie

Comment: Now that i saw your answer, you dont want to know. :-D

Comment: You make me curious :P

Comment: Its embarrassing. :-/

Comment: Believe me I know people. I already saw the worst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be the easy way:

```
newlist =[]
for item in oldlist:
    newlist.append(item)
    newlist.append(item+'.')
    newlist.append(item+',')
    newlist.append(item+'?')
    newlist.append(item+'!')
    newlist.append(item+':')
```

A little shorter:

```
newlist =[]
adds = ['', ',', '.', '?', '!', ':']
for item in oldlist:
    for add in adds:
        newlist.append(item+add)
```

OR as list comprehension:

```
adds = ['', ',', '.', '?', '!', ':']
newlist = [item+add for item in oldlist for add in adds]
```

As a one liner:

```
newlist = [item+add for item in oldlist for add in ['', ',', '.', '?', '!', ':']]
```

Comment: Thats great, thanks! I will go with the list comprehension, working great.

Answer (score 1):

Some functional love

```
from itertools import product 

l1 = ['This', 'Hello', 'Good']
l2 = ['', '.', ',', '?', '!', ':']

newlist = ["".join(e) for e in product(l1, l2)]

print newlist
```